# "Having to" usage

Tags: grammar, nouns, modal-verbs

I am confused in the usage of "having to" in a sentence, mentioned below. Which one is correct/appropriate?

> The trouble is having to backup …

or

> The trouble is in having to backup …

I would appreciate some suggestions.

Comment: not an issue with "having to" as much as an issue with is / is in - "the problem is in (the) delivery" vs "the problem is (the) delivery". You might also find [ell](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) very useful

Comment: Thank you, but I still did not understand which of the two is more appropriate. "is" or "is in"? 
Because in your example the meaning changes if "is in" is used instead of "is", but in my example it does not make a significant difference.

Comment: Good question. There's a real grammatical difference, even though the meanings are essentially the same.

Comment: Both are correct but slightly different. One says the trouble is the process itself. The other says the trouble is a part of the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grammatically, both phrases are fine. Both phrases could be made into sentences which mean essentially the same thing. However, when you change the punctuation only slightly and add a single word, the emphasis in the sentence also changes slightly, as you will see. I'll illustrate the differences in emphasis by using some sentences of my own creation, each of which is preceded by a question, to give each sentence a better context.

> Q: So, Ted, could you summarize the problem you have been having with the new laser printer?
>
> A: Yes. From my perspective, the trouble *is having to* replace the ink cartridge after having made only about 200 copies, which is prohibitively costly, given the volume of printing we do.

Or,

> Q: So, Ted, could you summarize the problem you have been having with the new laser printer?
>
> A: Yes. From my perspective, the trouble is, *in having to* replace the ink cartridge after having made only about 200 copies, we incur a prohibitive cost, given the volume of printing we do.

Can you see the slight change in emphasis? The two "answers" give essentially the same information, but the emphasis changes from

> having to *replace* the ink cartridge,

to

> a prohibitive *cost*

Perhaps another illustration would help.

> The trouble with Rachel is having to explain the procedure to her a hundred times before she catches on, *which* [the added word] decreases our productivity significantly.

Or,

> The trouble with Rachel is, in having to explain the procedure to her a hundred times before she catches on, our productivity decreases significantly.

Again, the emphases of the two sentences are slightly different. The first sentence emphasizes

> having to *explain* the procedure,

whereas the second sentence emphasizes that

> our *productivity decreases* significantly

I realize that by separating the *is* and the *in* we change the sentences' construction, but I think you can see how the emphases differ.

I'm also curious as to whether a test-subject listener could detect a difference in emphases between the two sentences. If so, could there be a statistical significance as to which segment of the sentences is recalled better than another segment?

I imagine that only a rhetorician or student of communication would find such a study interesting. On the other hand, since all of us communicate, more people than not would be interested in knowing how and what improves our listeners' understanding and retention of what we say. Everyone wants to be understood, yes?